# Tensorflow: AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'Supervisor'

Tags: tensorflow

I'm trying to use the Supervisor class to create checkpoints that can be used to save/load partial trainings, as mentioned in the TensorFlow documentation - https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/supervisor .

But when I try to use it as mentioned in the docs -

```
sv = tf.Supervisor(logdir="/checkpoints")` 
with sv.managed_session() as sess:
```

It throws the below error -

> Tensorflow: AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'Supervisor'

Whats am I missing?

Comment: might be `sv = tf.train.Supervisor`

Comment: Thanks, yes looks like that's what it was. Feel free to post it as an answer.

Comment: eh, this is more a typo than an answer-worthy question. If you're feeling less lazy than me, you might want to file an issue for the documentation.